# Django StaticCompilationError, extend ' .clearfix' has no matches

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm working on a Django application and all of a sudden I'm getting the error `extend ' .clearfix' has no matches` and this occurs at `Exception Location:  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/static_precompiler/compilers/less.py in compile_file, line 41`, when I try to connect to the server.

I have never had this issue before, and I even added in `@import (reference) "utilities.less";` to the `bootstrap.less` file ("utilities.less" contains the definition of .clearfix), yet I still get the issue.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, my lessc version is `lessc 2.6.0`

Comment: I recall certain Less versions (`2.3.x...2.4.x`) reported a false warning for actually properly matched `extend`. I.e. identify the Less version you're using and update if possible.

Comment: @seven-phases-max the version number is `2.6.0` and I updated the question to contain that. Is there a way I can revert to `2.1`? I can't for the life of my find anywhere online explaining how to downgrade lessc versions...

Comment: Then the warning is correct and somewhere in your code you actually have that not matching `extend`. The problem is that it's a *warning* and not a *error* as Django seems to interpreter it. As for downgrading, I suppose you can try.

Comment: I'm really dumbfounded as to why it's occurring. Everyone else can run the server from the master branch with no issues which is why I believe it's version-related. @seven-phases-max could you guide me to where I could learn how to downgrade lessc? Their website has no docs on downgrading and uninstalling through npm isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue by downgrading to less 2.1.

I did so by running the following commands:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g less
sudo npm install -g less@2.1
```

It seems that part of our codebase isn't compatible with less 2.6!